# highchart : add point without changing the series' line

Tags: highcharts

I need to add a point on the line -not anywhere- on click without changing the line , then add two lines (like crosshair or plotline) that intersect with the point.

I have tried to use the "addPoint" function but it changes the serie's line .

[image: external img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [allowPointSelect](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.allowPointSelect) as true and then configure state of marker by [options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.states.select). Next step is catch [click event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click) on point and use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) to add custom shapes.

```
series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            marker: {
                states: {
                    select: {
                        enabled: true,
                        fillColor: 'red',
                        color: 'red'
                    }
                },
            },
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        var chart = this.series.chart,
                            r = chart.renderer,
                            left = chart.plotLeft,
                            top = chart.plotTop,
                            width = chart.plotWidth,
                            height = chart.plotHeight,
                            x = this.plotX,
                            y = this.plotY;

                        if (this.series.options.enabledCrosshairs) {
                            if (crosshair !== UNDEFINED) crosshair.destroy();

                            crosshair = r.path(['M', left, top + y, 'L', left + x, top + y, 'M', left + x, top + y, 'L', left + x, top + height])
                                .attr({
                                'stroke-width': 1,
                                stroke: 'red'
                            })
                                .add();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u4ha3cxw/15/
Example with click on a series: jsfiddle.net/u4ha3cxw/17

Comment: Thank you so much for this.
this solves 70% of my problem, can i add a point  on "the non selectable area" of the line where there isn't a point without changing the line?

Comment: Could you attach a mockup of that?

Comment: I've already done that on the picture above , i want to add the point on the line (between two points) .

Comment: You need to catch series click event and refer to e object to extract coordinates. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u4ha3cxw/17/ Only what you need is add "marker" like circle by [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.circle)